# Payment method's name is not showing

Tags: payment-methods, ce-1.9.1.0

In back-end Order View Page I can see only "*Order was placed using CURRENCY*" and I can't find out if customer chose to pay *In cash* or by *Credit card on delivery*.

Any idea? Thank you

EDIT: The payment method isn't showed in pdf invoice as well.

Answer (score 2):

The section that you have mentioned is simply to show the order currency code. You can find it under `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml`

```
<div><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order was placed using %s', $_order->getOrderCurrencyCode()) ?></div>
```

Payment information should be shown via a separate block added via `<?php echo $this->getPaymentHtml() ?>`

This should show the block with name `order_payment` and type `adminhtml/sales_order_payment`.

In the end the display is controlled via the helper `Mage_Payment_Helper_Data::getInfoBlock` I would suggest that you should look into this function to be able to debug the problem.

Comment: To be honest I don't know how to find problem in function. I went around and I used this function to show payment method in adminpanel `$payment_method = $_order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();`

Answer (score 0):

Goto System / Configuration / Payment Methods and check where the translation is set. I could set to empty.

Maybe you have to search bottom-up, so select the storeview first and see where the text is set.

Comment: I have set title on every level (default, main website, my website) its still empty. And its empty even with different languages.

Comment: Than I do not know it :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it wrongly translated?

Look in

- db `core_translate`
- themes `app/design/frontend/package/theme/locale/your_locale/translate.csv`
- modules `app/locale/your_locale/*.csv`

Comment: I guess it isn't. When I switch to US english, GB english, deutsch and etc. it still not showing anything.